# Issue calling something on the UI Thread from inside a callback in c++/cx

Tags: visual-studio, asynchronous, dispatcher, c++-cx, ui-thread

This is my Callback function:

```
void VideoCapturerSampleCallback(struct LmiVideoCapturer_* capturer, const LmiVideoFrame* videoFrame, LmiVoidPtr userData)
{
  //TODO will have to be on ui thread;
  Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(0, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this]()
{
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage^ bitmapImage =
        ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage();
    auto uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg");
    if (first){
        first = false;
    }
    else{
        uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg");
        first = true;
    }
    bitmapImage->UriSource = uri;
    media->Source = bitmapImage;
}));
}
```

Which will basically change the picture every time the callback will be called, for now, I just change 2 pictures from Assets, in order to see if it works.
This is the error I get in the logs:

```
Error   17  error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation C:\Users\Alin Rosu\Downloads\App2\App2\MainPage.xaml.cpp    109 1   App2
Error   16  error C3482: 'this' can only be used as a lambda capture within a non-static member function    C:\Users\Alin Rosu\Downloads\App2\App2\MainPage.xaml.cpp    93  1   App2
19  IntelliSense: 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function    c:\Users\Alin Rosu\Downloads\App2\App2\MainPage.xaml.cpp    93  144 App2
18  IntelliSense: function "Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcher::RunAsync" cannot be called with the given argument list
        argument types are: (int, Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler ^)
        object type is: Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcher ^ c:\Users\Alin Rosu\Downloads\App2\App2\MainPage.xaml.cpp    93  84  App2
```

Now is it possible to use that [this] inside the callback, without getting an error?
I am a Android developer, so for me the logic response to this, was creating a global variable App2::MainPage, and then in the constructor, save "this" in it, so that I would have the context over there, and try to call RunAsync with that, but it does not work.
Is it possible to instantiate the DispatchedHandler another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declared the context like this:

```
App2::MainPage^ context;
```

Then set it in the MainPage function:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
media = this->player;
context = this;
}
```

And then I did it this way inside the VideoCapturerSampleCallback:

```
void VideoCapturerSampleCallback(struct LmiVideoCapturer_* capturer, const LmiVideoFrame* videoFrame, LmiVoidPtr userData)
{
App2::MainPage^ ctx = context;
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([ctx]()
{
    //TODO will need to set in here
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage^ bitmapImage =
        ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage();
    auto uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg");
    if (first){
        XTRACE(L"===================FIIIIIIIIIIIIRST =======================\n");
        first = false;
    }
    else{
        XTRACE(L"===================FIIIIIIIIIIIIRST FAAAALSEEEEE=======================\n");
        uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/2.jpg");
        first = true;
    }
    bitmapImage->UriSource = uri;
    media->Source = bitmapImage;
}));
}
```

This resolved my issues and I am able to modify the UI, being on the UI Thread.